# Get external custom product data vis POST and add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In our theme is a additional customize-button which send via POST the following information to an external customizer-script:

- user ID
- product ID
- product properties

This script was developed to work outside of Wordpress/WooCommerce as product-customizer, which should add customizations via POST back to woocommerce into the cart.

**Problem**: My plan was to POST these data back to WooCommerce, which should run/call a add-to-cart routine. But to be honest, I don't know how to toggle this. (add-to-cart externally)

If this isn't possible, I know a alternative solution. (integrate product-customizer into wordpress/wooommerce and exchange data via JS into hidden fields on product-page) But to integrate that, it would create some disadvantages and cost additional time to change.

**My question**: Is it possible to call/run add-to-cart via POST outside of woocommerce? I don't know how to catch/hook this.

I'm pleased with every hint I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I cannot see the wood for the trees.

In my alternative solution I talked about to use hidden fields and exchange them via JS.

Why I don't got the idea to POST to the product-page and add from there the data into the global... I don't know...

But now, problem/question solved.

Answer (score 0):

Im working on something similar right now...I've used the product IDs I want to customize externally and placed the value of these IDs for the input in my custom form through radio or whatever buttons for selection (or you can test using text type)

```
<form action="abc.com/customizerpage.php" method="POST">
  Product 1: <input type="radio" name = "product1" value="productIDnumber">
  <input type = "submit" value = "Send the Data Now">
</form>
```

(you can get the product ID number buy clicking on the woocommerce products and looking at the number in the URL or the variations would have the ID numbers as well)

the above form will POST the product ID to the external page (which of course you need to create that new php page.

customizerpage.php contains standard php content:

```
<?php
  $product1 = $_POST['product1'];
  echo $product1;
 /*now working on the URL to pass the ProductID back to the Cart or Checkout 
 pages in woocommerce. */
?>
```